# Array replaceAll() error

Tags: java, regex

I was wondering what's wrong with my regular expressions.I was trying to remove certain characters in a string with this code

```
array[i] = array[i].replaceAll("[.,;:?!\"')\\(]","");
```

Everything works except for the \ character, it wasn't removed from string. Also I tried this code

```
array[i] = array[i].replaceAll("[.,;:?!\"')(\\]","");
```

and it gave me an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try: `array[i] = array[i].replaceAll("[.,;:?!\\\"')(\]","");`

Comment: still won't work bro

Comment: @newbie whats the error?

Comment: @newbie that shouldn't give an error, what's the error?

Comment: with his suggestion, no error but it still won't delete the \

Comment: @newbie try `array[i] = array[i].replaceAll("[.,;:?!\\\\\"')(]","");`

Comment: @Codebender yup, of course fixed...

Comment: @UnknownOctopus op posted the comment as sol, what vihan suggested after my answer was , he just removed the backslashes which exists at the end and put four backslashes at the middle. How this completely differs from my answer? I don't care about accepts but i care about downvotes.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm not arguing who's correct. I was telling op the correct way to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following RegEx:

```
array[i] = array[i].replaceAll("[.,;:?!\\\\\"')(]","");
```

To match a single `\` in java, you need to use `\\` for every backslash. You need a total of four to match `\\` or a `\`. Hope that doesn't confuse you. This would match:

```
What is is | What Java thinks it is | What is actually is
,          | ,                      | ,
;          | ;                      | ;
:          | :                      | :
?          | ?                      | ?
!          | !                      | !
\\\\       | \\                     | \
\"         | "                      | "
'          | '                      | '
)          | )                      | )
(          | (                      | (
```

As you see in the above chart, it can be confusing with all the backslashes in Java RegExes, I really don't know a better solution but to count them out (*this one matches with that one, this with that, etc.*).

Comment: @AvinashRaj I originally proposed ~3 minutes [earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508872/array-replaceall-error/31508954#comment50980177_31508872), it's no problem

Comment: Solution in the above comment won't work.

Comment: @AvinashRaj _originally_ proposed. I didn't think he wanted to match ``\`` at first ;)